# In logstash, How to filter logs by json key and value?

Tags: json, logging, logstash

Currently I need to ignore some log in logstash.

my logstash input is as below:

```
 input {
    udp {
            port => 5001
            format => "json"
            type => "udp"
    }
 }
```

logs like {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}  will send to port 5001

I like to drop all logs that with "key1":"value1", how can I achieve it?

I'v tried

```
filter {
    grep {
            match => { "key1" => "value1" }
            negate => true
    }
}
```

it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

use the `if` syntax to do this:

```
filter {
  if [key1] == "value1" {
     drop {}
  }
}
```

Comment: it's doesn't work. does key1 can only be set in input{}?

Comment: i believe you need to change your input to say codec => json instead of format

Comment: I tested it with logstash 1.4 and putting `codec => json` works with the above snippet in the config file